# Good cucumber tutorial not dependent on rails

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

I'm looking for a good cucumber tutorial that doesn't force me to use rails. Any good Suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new book - [The Cucumber Book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) provides a great introduction to Cucumber and continues on where the RSpec book left off.  This new resource provides examples for non-rails application testing, both simple programs and also demonstrates how to do BDD on command line applications.

Overall it is a great resource and gives you a quick start guide and then dives into some of the detail.

The other resource, as others have stated, is the [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) reference.  Well worth a look at the tutorials.

And finally, [StackOverflow - Cucumber Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cucumber)

Answer (score 4):

I believe [The Rspec Book](http://pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book), starts you off in a non-Rails context.

Comment: I have the book. The book is nice for RSpec but covers little about Cucumber using outside rails.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the list in the Cucumber Wiki:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/tutorials-and-related-blog-posts

Lots of tutorials there :-)

Comment: the link ain't working :(
404

Answer (score 2):

Came across [Cukes4Ninja](http://cuke4ninja.com) - they have a simple tutorial that covers rails, .NET, and Java. It might provide what you're looking for.

Comment: It is a little outdated in the Java part, as Cuke4Duke has been abandoned and replaced with Cucumber-JVM (both made primarily by Aslak Hellesøy) - But I agree it is still the best.

Comment: @Svante, thanks for the pointer to Cucumber-JVM. Will have to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Look into this cucumber-watir [example project](https://github.com/napcs/cucumber_watir)

You can search for more open source projects in github or google code search

Answer (score 1):

My past two projects have not been Rails (or Ruby for that matter), and we've used Cucumber for both successfully.

They're both Web projects, and we were heavily inspired by these [two](https://github.com/cheezy/uitesting_blog) [samples](https://github.com/alisterscott/WatirMelonCucumber). I can't offer you a sample, since they're internal projects, but they're working very well for us.

Another team successfully used Cucumber to test an internal batch service that sends emails.

Answer (score 0):

The best for me has been cuke4ninja, http://cuke4ninja.com, which i found to be very detailed and aimed to get you started quick. So I'd suggest doing in in the following order, which worked for me:

1. website: Cuke4Ninja http://cuke4ninja.com
2. Book: the cucumber book by Matt Wynne 'The programatic programmer'
3. Book: The Rspec Book "David Chelimsky"