# How to execute .feature file in cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I am a beginner to Cucumber. I have installed cucumber by the help of internet. I have written a  .feature file. But I don`t know where to place this file and how to execute it.

Comment: Check out [Good cucumber tutorial not dependent on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5688757/841064)

Answer (score 1):

Because it wants you to succeed in BDD, cucumber will guide you through the process.  From the project directory, type `cucumber` in the cmd prompt or terminal, which returns:

```
You don't have a 'features' directory.  Please create one to get started.
```

Create a `features` directory, and put your `.feature` file in it.  Again, run `cucumber`, which returns pending step definitions that map to your `feature` file.  As an example:

```
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^I want to use cucumber$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Now--as @siekfried indicates--create a directory called `features/step_definitions` for your step definition files, which should end with `_steps` (e.g. `example_steps.rb`).  Then, edit your step definition file with the appropriate code to execute the step.